# Is it possible to detect the platform of my web clients in a verifiable way?

Tags: security, client-server

I have a web application that supports a variety of clients on various platforms including desktop browsers, mobile browsers, as well as mobile and tablet native applications.  I am wondering if it is possible to detect, **in a secure manner**, which of these platforms is being used to connect to the service.

This would be useful information to have, and would enable use cases where a security decision could be made based on the client platform.  For example, I could restrict access to certain portions of the service if a user was on a mobile client, or a browser with a known vulnerability.

I am aware of [EFF's Panopticlick research](https://panopticlick.eff.org/), which uses a variety of browser-based attributes, such as User-Agent string, installed plugins, screen dimensions, etc. to establish a unique fingerprint for a client, but this doesn't meet the "verifiable" requirement, as all the information is compiled on the client and could easily be spoofed.

I need a solution that is verifiable on the server side that the information sent by the client is accurate.  Does such a solution exist?

Comment: And welcome to upvote privileges btw :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to know which user-agent/platform you're dealing with, because ultimately any information you might use to identify them comes from the client side.

Any attribute you use to fingerprint my browser or operating system can be faked by simply sending you different HTTP headers.  There are dozens of browser-level HTTP header manipulators and HTTP request code libraries that do precisely that.

I would therefore highly recommend against making -any- security decision based on platform or user-agent of the client.  Assume that whatever rules you may set for purposes of usability along those lines can be violated by a hacker.